Dividing Factors Containing Variables with Inequalities
I made a post earlier about this topic, but it was poorly phrased and unorganized. Here is my attempt at clarifying my main concern.
Suppose we have the following inequality:
$$ x > 0 $$
In a trivial way, x values that are greater than 0 satisfy this inequality; so, the solution is all positive real numbers. However, since $x \neq 0 $, it is perfectly legal to divide both sides of this inequality by x. Since x > 0, we can also divide by x without flipping the inequality. The resulting inequality is simply:
$$ 1 > 0 $$
Notice that all x values trivially satisfy this inequality. So, the solution is now all real numbers. This seems like a contradiction, given that before dividing by x (a perfectly legal move), our solution was simply positive real numbers.
I write all of this to ask: How does dividing by factors that contain x affect our solution when it comes to inequalities?
When it comes to equations, I know that dividing by a factoring containing x (such as $x-5$ in the equation $(x-5)(x+2) = 0 $) simply restricts our domain in some way. In the example I just provided, dividing by $(x-5)$ yields a new equation $(x+2) = 0$ with a domain restriction $x\neq5$ since we divided by $(x-5)$ to derive this equation. When I divided x in the original inequality to derive the $1 > 0$ inequality, is there an associated restriction placed on the domain of x? If so, what is it, and how do I obtain it?

$x$ can't be zero. $x$ has to be positive in order for the sign not to change. If $x$ is negative, sign changes.

Why does the resulting solution for the new inequality have a solution space of all real numbers, whereas the original only has a solution space of positive real numbers? @Gwen
